# Use modern GET parameters with DRF Router

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The goal is to accept GET parameters after the question mark, for example

`api/items?name=apple?starting=10_10_2020`

Strange but simple router `path('api/items)` is not working

Should I add something?
Thank you

Comment: How come is this "modern"? You should separate different query string parameters with ampersands (&)

Comment: Please include your router and view.

Comment: You don't need anything to accept the query parameters

Comment: @AKX meaning it should look like `api/items&name=apple&starting=2020` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the default router for this purpose. You can use this example to map it according to your requirement.
**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import ItemsViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'items', ItemsViewSet,  basename='items')
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),]
```

**views.py**

```
class ItemsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ItemsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        name = self.request.query_params.get('name', None)
        starting = self.request.query_params.get('starting', None)
        queryset = Items.objects.filter(name=apple, starting=starting)
        return queryset
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Items

class ItemsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Items
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now you can access the items using this url `api/items?name=apple&starting=10-10-2020`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle the view is to use DjangoFilterBackend, if you are willing to import from django_filters:

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend


class ItemsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ItemsSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['name', 'starting']
```

With this approach, the parameters are optional, whereas the above approach will query for name=None and starting=None if the parameters are not provided.